# Spring cloud gateway hystrix not working

Tags: spring-cloud

I am having issues getting hystrix to work with my route.  things like re-write paths and load balancing are working but for some reason hystrix never trips.  I am setting my timeouts very low and have a delay in a downstream service.  Is there anything special you need to do to get hystrix working?

I am using spring-cloud-gateway with eureka and spring-cloud-config.  Also, is there a way to debug when a route is not working?  Like a log setting to see what is happening?

Here is my route:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      # =====================================
      - id: main-service
        uri: lbl://main-service
        predicates:
        - Path=/main-service**
        filters:
        - Hystrix=mainservice
```

Here is my pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-
        8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Here is my Application class:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableHystrix
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
  }
```

The only other class in the jar is this:

```
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfiguration {

@Bean
public DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator 
      discoveryClientRouteLocator(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {

    return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(discoveryClient);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you included the Hystrix starter?

Comment: Yes, hystrix starter has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  It seems that if you add eureka discovery then it automatically add routes that match all the spring.application.names returned by your eureka server and these have the same order as the ones I defined using application name as the predicate.  I was able to fix this by setting the order for my route to -1.

Not sure if there is a better way to do this but at least I know hystrix is working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
</dependency>
```